# What Analytics events are shown by Crashlytics leading up to a crash?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

It looks like as of Firebase 5.10.0 only sometimes some Analytics events are shown, and it looks like the events logged are happening after the crash. For many crashes, there are no analytics events.

Why is it that some crashes don't have any events attached to them? Are the events logged happening before or after the crash?

*Example where all events happened after the crash*

[image: l]

Answer (score 0):

Some analytics events are auto generated and may not show up if the crash occurs too early. Also make sure that all the custom logged events are being set before the crash occurs.